# MASM not assembling all files

Tags: visual-studio, masm, visual-studio-2022, masm64

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio 2022, which creates a .dll which calls a function created by the MASM assembler. The assembler - ml64 - however does not consider a single `.inc` file, and so fails with a `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol` error.

I have one file, `Core.asm` which links to `V.inc` which in turn links to `V_Constants.inc`. The files are linked together using `include`, so `Core.asm` has `include V.inc`, which in turn has `include V_Constants.inc`.

Initially this worked well, however when I changed `Core.asm` in a trivial way, everything stopped. I can empty the file to rule out any weird syntax errors and I get the same.

Changing the output to show what it is doing (as much as possible, by removing the /nologo command line) shows that the assembler is missing out `V.inc`, yet including everything else.

What could possibly stop `ml64.exe` from ignoring a file? Is it possible to force the assembly?

Interestingly if I rename `V.inc` I get a `cannot open file: v.inc` error. So it knows to include this file, yet it doesn't want to assemble it.

Comment: Without seeing a minimal complete example it is hard to say. Can you put the contetnts of all the files (the includes in question) and core.asm in your question. You did say "Initially this worked well, however when I changed Core.asm in a trivial way, everything stopped. I can empty the file to rule out any weird syntax errors and I get the same." I'd be curious what the trivial change was.

Comment: So when looking how to explain what is going on, it appears the Include in the `.vcxproj` has changed. Why would VS do that?!

Comment: Okay, I got your project but can't actually build it as you are (I'm using VS 2019) and I don't have all the required dependencies. But I think what is happening is that it is trying to assemble the .INC files. You don't assemble the INC files, just the ASM files that may include them. So `core.asm` should be assembled but the INC files shouldn't be. What happens if you mark both INC files as TEXT?

Comment: Thank you for looking, I've tried many combinations none seem to work with the same error. I'll try to boil it down to a basic example and post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something in Visual Studio 2022 changed the include element in the xml in the `.vcxproj` file, from `MASM` to `text`. I have no idea why.

This is what I had, note the wrong element for `V.inc`.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <MASM Include="Core.asm" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MASM Include="V_Constants.inc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Text Include="V.inc" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

---

*Edit* : So it turns out the original issue is that the main .asm file needs to include the external files. These cannot be be included as `MASM` elements in the project file.

In addition, I had `END` directives at the end of these `.inc` files, this is incorrect as it stops the processing. (I added these as when the files had a `MASM` element the assembler would complain about there not being an `END`. This was a big red-herring, and lead me down the wrong path.)

tl;dr: Files that are included should be marked as `Text`, and don't add an `END` to these files!

---

*Edit 2*: However, marking these files as text stops the project from being recompiled when they are changed.

Comment: You haven't told it to actually assemble the INC files directly have you? You don't assemble INC files. You just assemble the ASM files that may rely on those iNC files.

Comment: No, I just added them, `include`'d them, and it initially worked. Something in VS would appear to have changed the elements. I do think something else is at play here, as its still not compiling, even with empty files but maybe that's a different question.

Comment: Any chance you can put the project (including the VS project files and everything else) onto Github to look at?